# Conditional Visibility of rows in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm very new to SSRS 2008.Here is my problem/question.
I have 15-20 check boxes in the web interface on which the report is based on.I gave ID values to all the check boxes and passing the values of the selected checkboxes into the table so that I can get them on the report side.

On the report side,if a check box is not selected I've to hide that row.For instance if the column name on the table(REPORTCRITERIA) is LOCATIONS and if it has values (1,2,3).This means that checkboxes 1,2 and 3 are selected.how do I query that so that I can accomplish what I want?

Please help.

Thanks,
Praveen.

Comment: Can you add some example of what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe what you want back from your query and what you want displayed. I'm having trouble knowing what rows you want hidden. Is the table called ReportCriteria also what you want displayed on your report?

Answer (score 2):

In Report Designer, left-click the detail row, choose Row Visibility from the context menu, and use an IIF(Condition, True, False) for Hidden, meaning if the Condition holds the row will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Example that shows a specific text box ONLY on the very last page of the report:

Visibility / Show Or Hide based on an expression: 
=Globals!PageNumber < Globals!TotalPages

The expression HIDES the text box element only when this expression is true, and it will UNHIDE (show the element) when the expression turns FALSE.

Hope this helps,
If not, drop me a line or two.

Alejandro.-